# Update or create if not exist Mongo 3.0.4

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, upsert

I have collection having below data structure

`{
    "Shop": "123",
    "date": "28-05-2015",
    "Points": {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
    }
}`

Here shop and date has unique indexes and no id is there except _id ,
So if I want to update only b's value and if the record matching(based on account and date ) is not there than should create new record having same structure with b's value.
The most important part is its bulk operation means I need to create/update record per day for all the shops and these record will create for every shop per day .So while update a point if record is not there than create it else update the existing record .I am using spring .
I tried using update with upsert true but it's not updating rather creating a new record with only updated value .And what is best way  to update multiple shop with given updated  points .

Comment: can you post the upsert code here.

Comment: I was doing it on the Mongo shell itself. using update query with upset flag as a true... in mongo 3.4 there is $set flag in update that was working but it's not in 3.0. mean while I'll update code in few hours.

Comment: i will add some sample code you may verify it against your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//search a document that doesn't exist
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("points.b").is("some value"));

Update update = new Update();
update.set("b", some value);
update.set..... //set all needed fields else they go as null

mongoOperation.upsert(query, update, Shop.class);

Shop shopTestObj = mongoOperation.findOne(query, Shop.class);
System.out.println("shopTestObj - " + shopTestObj );
```

in case of bulk operation

```
// Sample code
com.mongodb.DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("shop");

// Get  BulkWriteOperation by accessing the mongodb com.mongodb.DBCollection class on mycol //Collection

BulkWriteOperation  bulkWriteOperation= collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();

//perform the upsert  operation in the loop to add objects for bulk execution 
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
// get a bulkWriteRequestBuilder by issuing find on the shop with _id
BulkWriteRequestBuilder bulkWriteRequestBuilder=bulkWriteOperation.find(new BasicDBObject('_id',Integer.valueOf(i)));

// get hold of upsert operation from bulkWriteRequestBuilder
BulkUpdateRequestBuilder updateReq=              bulkWriteRequestBuilder?.upsert()

updateReq. replaceOne (new BasicDBObject("_id",Integer.valueOf(i)).append("points.b", "some value"));

}
// execute bulk operation on shop collection
BulkWriteResult result=bulkWriteOperation.execute();
```

Comment: is there any reason to BulkWriteRequestBuilder is  based on _id or upsert is based on _id ?

Comment: thats just a sample.

Comment: i got the upper part without bulk update .Can you explain bulk update part  and if i have a list of object and lets say shop and date is unique so i want to UPOATE a , b only than how this will work and also you are using BasicDBObject , How can i use my objects instead of that

Comment: The above simple upsert is not having correct behavior its when i want to update only one field its creating record only having that field and creating new record with it .